# If $\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} a_{k}$ diverges, then one of its rearrangement converges to 1

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification

If $\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} a_{k}$ diverges, then there exists a rearrangment of $\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} a_{k}$ that converges to 1.

This is not true. A counter example I came up with is $\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}n$. The series diverges, but there isn't a rearrangement that goes to 0. Is this correct?

Comment: Let all of the $a_k<0$.

Also, your title and your question seem to be asking different things.

Comment: It doesn't hold for every arbitrary sequence, but it does for conditionally convergent alternating sequences.  See the [Riemann series theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem).

Comment: $a_k=1$ is a perfectly good counterexample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It holds if $a_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ and both $\sum_n \max(a_n, 0) = \infty$ and $\sum_n \max(-a_n,0) = \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. The common theorem is that if $\sum_k a_k$ is convergent but not absolutely convergent, for every $c$ there is a rearrangement converging to $c$. But if there is no requirement on convergence, this theorem is false. A simple example is $a_k = 1$: clearly any rearrangement leaves this sequence unchanged so no rearrangement converges to any value.